# Inkscape perspective tool automatically rotates the final path

Tags: inkscape, vector

I'm using **Inkcape 1.1** in **Linux**.

When I use perspective tool from *Extentions → Modify Path → Prespective,* the final result is rotated automatically.

Suppose, these are my two paths:

[image]

… and after using *perspective,* I get:

[image]

You can see the result rotated. How can I put it in perspective without rotating?
This happens only when I use *text on path*.
The problem was about the Bézier tool. I designed the perspective template with a “Bézier pen”.

It is important to know the starting point of the drawing and the path to draw.
This is the right path for working perspective correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Inkscape 1.1 there's no need to use that extension.

You can use the Perspective/Envelope LPE instead. Note that for this to work on text, it needs to be converted to outlines.

1. Make sure your artwork is grouped and the group is selected
2. Do *Path > Path Effects*, and click the + icon in the Path Effects panel to add a new path effect, search for "perspective". Select it
3. Switch to the Edit Paths by Nodes tool (N), and click and drag the corner controls to distort the image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a good tutorial, thank you. But Extentions did it automatically, this is manual :)

Comment: @sam sure, but this is easier since you can click and drag the controls to distort exactly as you wish. It's an improvement on that old extension.  Also with the old extension you need to draw a rectangle to make the transform which is a manual operation anyway.

Comment: It was good advice. Let me test. Thank

Comment: @sam - also note that the old Perspective extension still works, however there are special requirements for drawing the target shape. The rectangle needs to be drawn using the Pen Tool, starting from the bottom left corner in a clockwise direction, otherwise it won't work properly.